# How to read a Version element value from an XML file

Tags: xml, vb.net

I'm trying to read the version of an xml file:

```
<Order xsi:schemaLocation="urn:schemas-basda-org:2000:purchaseOrder:xdr:3.01 order-v3.xsd urn:schemas-bossfed-co-uk:OP-Order-v1 OP-Order-v1.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="urn:schemas-basda-org:2000:purchaseOrder:xdr:3.01">
  <OrderHead>
    <Schema>
      <Version>3.05</Version>
    </Schema>
    <Parameters>
      <Language>en-GB</Language>
      <DecimalSeparator>.</DecimalSeparator>
      <Precision>12.1</Precision>
    </Parameters>
    <OrderCurrency>
      <Currency Code="GBP">GB Pounds</Currency>
    </OrderCurrency>
  </OrderHead>
```

The code I'm trying to use is:

```vb
Dim m_xmld As XmlDocument
Dim m_nodelist As XmlNodeList
Dim m_node As XmlNode

'Create the XML Document
m_xmld = New XmlDocument()

'Load the Xml file
m_xmld.Load(fileLocation)

'Show all data in your xml
MessageBox.Show(m_xmld.OuterXml)

'Get the list of name nodes
m_nodelist = m_xmld.SelectNodes("/Order/OrderHead/Schema")

For Each m_node In m_nodelist
    GetXmlVersion = m_node.Attributes.GetNamedItem("Version").Value
Next
```

But, it doesent pull anything.

i changed it to:

```
Public Shared Function GetXmlVersion (ByVal fileLocation As String) As String
    Dim m_xmld As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument()
    m_xmld.Load (fileLocation)
    GetXmlVersion = m_xmld.SelectSingleNode ("/Order/OrderHead/Schema/Version").InnerText
End Function
```

and i just get

NullReferenceException was Unhandled
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

because the m_xmld.selectsinglenode is null

Comment: You are not showing a full working sample of your XML which reproduces the problem.  When I test it, it works fine, but to get it to work I have to add the end tags and take out the `xsi:schemaLocation` attribute because that namespace is undefined.  In particular, you need to show the default namespace, if there is one.  If there is a default namespace defined, that would definitely stop your code from working.

Comment: i have updated the xml i wasnt aware that the schemaLocation effected the reading of the xml nodes. Thanks

Comment: is there anyway i can read this xml while ignoring the schemas? as the work i will be doing with this file doesent need access to them thanks again

Comment: Unfortunately, no.  See my answer for an explanation and solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first problem is that you are trying to read the Version as an attribute instead of as a child element.

The second problem is that your XML document has a default namespace.  That means that even though none of the elements explicitly specify a namespace prefix, they actually do belong to the `urn:schemas-basda-org:2000:purchaseOrder:xdr:3.01` namespace.  As you may be aware, the `SelectSingleNode` method uses XPath to find the matching nodes.  What you may not know, it that there is no way to force XPath to use a default namespace.  As such, you need to specify the correct namespace for every node name that belongs to any namespace.  To quote the relevant paragraph from the [Official XPath Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#node-tests):

> A QName in the node test is expanded into an expanded-name using the
>   namespace declarations from the expression context. This is the same
>   way expansion is done for element type names in start and end-tags
>   except that the default namespace declared with xmlns is not used: **if
>   the QName does not have a prefix, then the namespace URI is null** (this
>   is the same way attribute names are expanded). It is an error if the
>   QName has a prefix for which there is no namespace declaration in the
>   expression context.

Therefore, you need to do something like this:

```
Public Shared Function GetXmlVersion(ByVal fileLocation As String) As String
    Dim xmld As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument()
    xmld.Load(fileLocation)
    Dim manager As XmlNamespaceManager = New XmlNamespaceManager(xmld.NameTable)
    manager.AddNamespace("n", xmld.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI)
    Return xmld.SelectSingleNode("/n:Order/n:OrderHead/n:Schema/n:Version", manager).InnerText
End Function
```

In this example, `xmld.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI` returns the default namespace URI for the root element (`urn:schemas-basda-org:2000:purchaseOrder:xdr:3.01`).  We assign it the prefix of "n", so then we need to put an "n:" prefix on every element name in the XPath.

Also, you'll note that I changed the `GetXmlVersion =` line to `Return`.  Using the `Return` keyword is the preferred method in VB.NET.  Also, I changed the name of your `m_xmld` variable to `xmld` because it was confusing.  Typically, when people prefix a variable name in VB with an `m_`, that is to indicate that it is a private field of the class (a private variable declared at the class level, outside of any method).  That is not the case here.  `xmld` is just a local method variable.

Comment: Thanks for your help i have changed my origanal post i just get a null reference error now because the query still doesent pull anything

Comment: @Houlahan Thanks, Please see my updated answer for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Version is a child element of Schema, not an attribute.

Comment: so it is!  GetXmlVersion = m_node.ChildNodes("Version").Value still pulls nothing though. the m_nodelist ='s nothing when its done the select nodes of ("/Order/OrderHead/Schema") Thanks